# What are the reasons and/or benefits Scala can compare incompatible objects?

Tags: scala, comparison

This puzzles me -- I have read the reasons Scala exists at all, and the common-sense presented appeals to me, for example choosing static typing (because of less errors). Yet, you can compare (out of the box, by default) completely different, irrelevant objects and it compiles and runs fine. For me it just begs for more errors in code.

Could someone please explain what are the reasons for such feature? Or benefits?

**I know how Scala works in the matter of comparison.** I am asking **WHY** it works that way.

I would expect, that if I want to do this, I would write implicit conversion or explicit comparison. That approach makes perfect sense for me, current Scala way -- no, and thus my question.

And one more thing -- I am not looking how to use Scala-way comparison for some fancy effects, I am looking for more strict error checking. IOW: I don't want to compare Orange and Apple by color, I want to forbid such comparison by default unless user explicitly say it is OK to compare such types.

#### Example

```
class Test
{
  val s : String = "ala"
}

class Foo
{
  val x : Int = 5
}

object Testbed 
{
  def main(args : Array[String])
  {
    val t = new Test
    val f = new Foo
    if (t==f)
      println("match")
    else
      println("no")
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post a snippet of code with something you think should not compile but does?

Comment: @Paolo Falabella, for me the code in the example (above) does not make sense, or IOW: I should get error from compiler.

Comment: There was a recent proposal to gradually change the equality operator to a type-safe one on the mailing lists https://groups.google.com/group/scala-internals/browse_thread/thread/321211df4998b7e3/8adcb751752f649f . But a month ago, Martin explained "It seems this requires a fudamental rethinking how equality of case classes 
is handled. That won't happen for any 2.9.x, I think."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the simple answer is that == is designed to be compatible with `java.lang.Object.equals()`. Since any class can override `equals()` it's impossible for the Scala compiler to determine the result of an equality check between two objects unless it knows the runtime class of the object at compile time (i.e. the static type must be a final class or the `new` invocation must be visible to the compiler when compiling the equality check) AND the `equals()` method is not overridden in this class or any super class.

So, in your example the compiler can indeed infer the runtime class of both `t` and `f` and issue a warning (not an error though) for the equality check, but in practice the cases where the runtime class can be inferred are quite rare. Note that scalac already issues warnings for some equality comparisons between primitive types and object types.

P.S. If you want a safer equality check use the `Equal` trait in Scalaz.

Comment: Aaah, I get it (I think so). It is similar to C# where basic Object type has burried several stupid methods and everything else has to inherit it. So anything can be called "equals" against anything, and since Scala works on values, not references... we have safety breach. Bad Java, bad!

Comment: @Jesper, great answer, but could you explain how the Scalaz `Equal` trait differs from Scala's built in `equals` method? Also, methods in the Scala standard library use the `equals` method; does Scalaz have a replacement for these? Thanks.

Comment: The big advantage with Scalaz's `===` operator is that you will get a compiler error if you try to compare two objects of type `T` unless there is an implicit instance of type `Equal[_ >: T]` (and of course there is no `Equal[Any]` instance :) ). I'm not familiar enough with Scalaz to say if it has replacements for methods which use `equals()` or `==`.

Answer (score 4):

Equality in scala is value equality (not reference) and what is equal to what can be defined by you by overriding `equals`. Basically == is not an operator in scala, but acts like (and in fact IS) a method on the object that you want to test for equality.
So `t == f` is actually `t.==(f)` where `==` is defined on `Any`, so you get it on every class in scala.

For instance (in your example) you can make your Test == to a Foo, like this:

```
class Test {
  val s : String = "ala"
}

class Foo {
  val x : Int = 5
  override def equals(that: Any) : Boolean = {
    that.isInstanceOf[Test] && this.x == 5 && that.asInstanceOf[Test].s=="ala";
  }  
}
```

and now you get:

```
scala> val t = new Test
t: Test = Test@86a58a

scala> val f = new Foo
f: Foo = Foo@104f889

scala> f==t
res3: Boolean = true
```

but (since we have NOT overridden equals on Test)

```
scala> t==f
res4: Boolean = false
```

While in this specific case this does not make a lot of sense, the point is that scala lets you decide what makes a Test equal to a Foo. Do you want a Person to be == to another Person (or to an Employee) if they have the same social security number? You can implement that logic.

However, with great power comes great responsibility and in fact [the concept of equality is surprisingly tricky](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html).

Comment: I know how Scala works in the matter of comparison. I am asking WHY it works that way. Most important, why I can compare objects of incompatible types out of the box? I would expect, that if I want to do this, I would write implicit conversion or explicit comparison.

Comment: to enforce that, scala would have probably thrown away compatibility with java

Comment: why? If I am not mistaken, you cannot compare Orange and Apple implicit way (like Scala), and on the other hand you have to provide the set or sub-set of Java features. So it seems OK to me.

Comment: @macias - Why?  Because for better or worse, Java defines `Object.equals()` to take an argument of `Object` - so `"foo".equals(3)` compiles just fine in Java, even though it'll always be false.  Scala's `==` is syntactic sugar for `java.lang.Object.equals`, so it *has to* behave the same; it can't "fix" core Java libraries, it has to just live with them.  See Scalaz's `===` operator (or its Unicode alias `≟`) if you want type-safety; `"foo" === 3` would fail to compile.

Comment: Yes, I want type safety for sure. Thank you for pointing out Scalaz.

Answer (score 1):

In recent trunk builds your example warns.  I think I found a good balance between likelihood of mis-warning and catching unintended comparisons.  It's harder than it looks in the presence of universal equality and subtyping.

```
% scalac3 ./a.scala 
./a.scala:20: warning: Test and Foo are unrelated: they will most likely never compare equal
    if (t==f)
         ^
one warning found
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for more strict error checking.

The recent (May 2016) post "[Multiversal Equality for Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/05/06/multiversal-equality.html)", written by the creator of Scala himself [Martin Odersky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Odersky), is trying to address that.

> The current status in Scala is that the compiler will give warnings for some comparisons that are always false. But the coverage is weak. For instance this will give a warning:

```
scala> 1 == "abc"
<console>:12: warning: comparing values of types Int and String using `==' will always yield false
```

> But this will not:

```
scala> "abc" == 1
res2: Boolean = false
```

> I believe to do better, we need to enlist the cooperation of developers.
>   Ultimately it’s the developer who provides implementations of equality methods and who is therefore best placed to characterize which equalities make sense.
>
> The best known way to characterize such relationships is with type classes.
>   Implicit values of a `trait Eq[T, U]` can capture the property that values of type `T` can be compared to values of type `U`.
>   Here’s the definition of `Eq`:

```
package scala
trait Eq[-T, -U]
```

> Given a set of `Eq` instances, the idea is that the Scala compiler will check every time it encounters a *potentially problematic* comparison between values of types `T` and `U` that there is an implicit instance of `Eq[T, U]`.
>   A comparison is potentially problematic if it is between incompatible types.
>   As long as `T <: U` or `U <: T` the equality could make sense because both sides can potentially be the same value.

Comment: see also https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/a7a4e5f68c070543516aed3e4ad3e3d6c787dce1